# DrRacket on Mac OSX: How do I install the default predefined teachpacks in BSL?

Tags: macos, racket

A student of mine is using DrRacket on Mac OSX.  She is using Beginning Student Language and would like to install Racket Teachpacks that normally ship with DrRacket.  However, selecting `Add Teachpack...` from the `Language` menu results in this disappointing outcome:

```
"The Teachpack menu is only available in these languages: 
Die Macht der Abstraktion - fortgeschri...
Intermediate Student with lambda
Advanced Student
```

Have we done something wrong with the installation?  How can we make Teachpacks available in Beginning Student Language?

Comment: Which version of Racket produces this error?

Comment: In 5.3.6, I can only produce the error when the language dialog box (bottom left) is "Determine language from source". The teachpack menu properly appears for me if any of the teaching languages are selected.

Comment: Try using a newer version of DrRacket.